# Asus 1015cx Eee PC stuck on blue BIOS screen, even after reset

Tags: boot, bios, eee-pc

I've been using this for the past 2 years without any trouble. I have easypeasy installed as the only OS. I left it on standby for a couple of hours with the charger plugged in, and when I tried to resume it, nothing came on. I shut it off with the power switch and then turned it back on. Since then, it only goes straight to the BIOS setup utility, no matter how many times I use <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to exit.

What seems to be the problem? I got a bunch of important files on this netbook, so any help to get it back running would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First check the boot order to make sure that the correct boot drive is selected, if that doesn't work try checking the SMART status of the drive. You can do this using GParted on a bootable USB.